# In Excel, Can I have two rows of (worksheet) tabs for my workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel, tabs, spreadsheet

I'm using Excel (2013). I have a workbook with numerous different worksheets, and would like to have them take up two rows of worksheet tabs rather than just one. Can I achieve this somehow? I can't find an appropriate setting in the Excel Options dialog.

Comment: Afraid that isn't possible at the moment, check out this question for some workarounds http://superuser.com/questions/351494/show-excel-sheet-tab-in-2-row

Comment: @J_V ok, voting to close as a duplicate of that one.