# Split worksheet names into second row in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a large workbook in Microsoft Excel 2013, with about 20 spreadsheets. The names are sort of long, so I can only see 5-7 at a time, with a very small scrollbar for navigating each spreadsheet.

Is there a way to have 2 rows in Excel, one for scrolling and clicking on spreadsheets, and one for scrolling the current spreadsheet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [show Excel sheet tab in >=2 row](http://superuser.com/questions/351494/show-excel-sheet-tab-in-2-row)

Comment: Looks like it has been [suggested to MS](https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/10203054-support-multi-row-worksheet-tabs-or-vertical-tabs).

Answer (score 1):

I have never found anything handy like that.

An alternative, is if you `right` click on the sheet navigation buttons, in the lower left corner, it will give you a list of sheets to choose from. This can save time moving to sheets that may not be in view.

[image]