# Working with an Excel with too many sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I'm working on an Excel file which have a LOT of sheets which makes navigating between sheets a headache.

Is there any way to show sheets in a column at left (instead of a row below cells), so I can see more at once and possibly search more easier.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/351517/910710

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Programming is the well know fastest mode, so that I  would like to suggest you VBA (Macro) Code will help  you to create List of Sheets in a New Sheet.**

**And you will be able to navigate between sheets just by click on the Sheet name.**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    Dim xSheet As Worksheet
    Dim xRow As Integer
    Dim calcState As Long
    Dim scrUpdateState As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    xRow                       = 1

    With Me
        .Columns(1).ClearContents
        .Cells(1, 1) = "Sheet-INDEX"
        .Cells(1, 1).Name = "SheetIndex"
    End With

    For Each xSheet In Application.Worksheets
        If xSheet.Name <> Me.Name Then
            xRow                     = xRow + 1
            With xSheet
                .Range("A1").Name = "Start_" & xSheet.Index
                .Hyperlinks.Add anchor: = .Range("A1"), Address: = "", _
                SubAddress:             = "Index", TextToDisplay: = "Back to Index"
            End With
            Me.Hyperlinks.Add anchor: = Me.Cells(xRow, 1), Address: = "", _
            SubAddress: = "Start_" & xSheet.Index, TextToDisplay: = xSheet.Name
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**How it works:**

1. Create a new worksheet and rename it as per your choice. like *SheetList* or *ListOfSheets*.
2. Right click at the new sheet name Tab & select **View Code** from menu.
3. In the popping window, Copy and Paste above shown VBA code into it.
4. Now RUN the Macro to create a Dynamic list of worksheets.

**Note,** *or as soon you click on New Sheet tab the code will create list of sheets, since code is for **Worksheet Activate event**.*

[image]

Comment: @mehrandvd glad to help you & happy that the solution is working for you,, keep asking ☺